# Audio Streams stops and resumes after a long time with the latest Exoplayer

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer

I'm trying to play a audio stream with the latest Exoplayer library. But audio gets stuck. Audio plays for some time and stops. And after 10-15 Minutes.

On searching I found that, it's not able to encode the stream. We cannot change the stream, as same stream is used in other platforms and its working fine in other platforms.

Some suggested to use old library. But there are many missing classes in old library. Library version I checked is Version 1.0.13.9. To use this, I need to change everything.

Is there any other workaround to fix this issue?

Observerd in logs:

Goes to buffering state twice and then, shows the below message

> AudioTrack﹕ Discontinuity detected [expected 373942856, got 373551020].

Current working version is 1.3.3.

Comment: what is the type of stream you are getting ?

Comment: @Murtaza Khursheed Hussain , I'm using MP3 stream format

Comment: could be a device specific issue, try to check it on another device.

Comment: @Murtaza Khursheed Hussain, this happend in Moto E too

Comment: its already reported.. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/398

Comment: @Murtaza Khursheed Hussain , they said, it's because of the retry policy. Is there a way to avoid retry policy?

Comment: Well I am not an expert in exoplayer, probably you can do that but you have to search on it a little. BTW I did but didn't found any, but I did found method which handle Discontinuity [here](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/) in **AudioTrack** class . Hope it helps

Comment: @Murtaza Khursheed Hussain, thanks. I too found where exactly it handles Discontinuity. I have to search how can I avoid it.

Comment: Hey @Murtaza Khursheed Hussain, Did you guys manage to solve this issue? I need your help can you please tell me how to handle this issue and reset the exoplayer. How to get call back for this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Reena no I was not able to solve the said problem